# Linking social provider with anonymous user on two devices

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

When a user start using our app we log him in using Firebase anonymous login.
We later allow them to login with social providers like Apple. We use the "auth().currentUser?.linkWithCredential" to link the social credentials with the anonymous user id.

We encountered a situation we are not sure how to solve:

1. User install the app on the device and use Sign in with Apple to sign in. We link the anonymous account to the Apple login and everything works just fine.
2. But now the user buys a new device. He installs the app and start it. He gets a new anonymous uid. He then try to sign in with Apple. Now if we try to call linkWithCredential we get an error:
   "auth/credential-already-in-use] This credential is already associated with a different user account"

This is of course true, as the Apple credentials were associated with the anonymous user on the old device.
So how do we allow a user to sign in again from a new device?
We thought to catch the error, and then call signInWithCredential instead of linkWithCredential. But then we get an error:
Duplicate credential received. Please try again with a new credential.

It seems you can't use the Apple credentials for more than one call.

So again - we are stuck with no way to allow a user to login in two devices.

```js
let appleAuthRequestResponse = null;
try {
  appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
    requestedOperation: AppleAuthRequestOperation.LOGIN,
    requestedScopes: [
      AppleAuthRequestScope.EMAIL,
      AppleAuthRequestScope.FULL_NAME,
    ],
  });
} catch (err) {
  // TODO: decide what to do
  return;
}

const {
  identityToken,
  nonce
} = appleAuthRequestResponse;
const appleCredential = auth.AppleAuthProvider.credential(
  identityToken,
  nonce
);

let userCredentials = null;

try {
  userCredentials = await auth().currentUser ? .linkWithCredential(
    appleCredential
  );
  // This will work on the first device but fail on the second one
  console.log(userCredentials);
} catch (err) {
  // This will fail as well with error: Duplicate credential received
  await auth().signInWithCredential(appleCredential)
}
```

Comment: If you think there is a bug or missing feature here, you can always file a report with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here is to add additional logic to your login flow. You can add an option to login with Apple or continue anonymous at the beginning, or offer the option to login with Apple if you get the "auth/credential-already-in-use" error code.